# React Testing Library / Jest - Child component not present when rendering parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test that a click handler in my child component that is changing the parent component's state and then displaying conditional jsx in my parent component, but I can't figure out the best way to do so and I'm also having trouble debugging. My other tests that test the parent component and child component separately are working (as in I'm able to find dom elements that I expect to be present), but when I try to test the clicking of a button in the child component by rendering the parent component, my test fails.

Expected behavior:

1. User clicks the div with className 'open-comparison-btn'
2. Child component calls the props.setModalShowing function with 'true'
3. Parent component modalShowing state is updated to true
4. Parent component re-renders and displays the conditional jsx className 'comparison-modal'

The functionality is working in the localhost browser, but not in my test, and I can't even find the child component's html at all in my test.

Parent component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ProductCard from './ProductCard.jsx';

const RelatedProducts = (props) => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(0);
  const componentName = 'RelatedProducts';
  const [modalShowing, setModalShowing] = useState(false);
  const [currentProduct, setCurrentProduct] = useState({});
  const [comparisonProduct, setComparisonProduct] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentProduct(props.currentProduct);
  }, [props.currentProduct]);

  const getFeatures = () => {
    return [...currentProduct.features, ...comparisonProduct.features]
      .filter((v, i, a)=>a.findIndex(v2=>(v.feature === v2.feature && v.value === v2.value)) === i);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className='related-products-container' role="listbox" aria-label="related products" style={{marginLeft: `-${position}px`}}>
        {props.relatedProducts ?
          props.relatedProducts.map((product) => {
            return <ProductCard
              modalShowing={modalShowing}
              setModalShowing={setModalShowing}
              setComparisonProduct={setComparisonProduct}
              key={product.id}
              product={product}
              generateStars={props.generateStars}
              isFetching={props.isFetching}
              setIsFetching={props.setIsFetching}
              parentComponent={componentName}
              yourOutfit={props.yourOutfit}
              addToOutfit={props.addToOutfit}
            />;
          })
          : null
        }

      </div>
      <div className='fade-top'>
        { position > 0 ?
          <div className="arrow-container-left" role="button" aria-label="scroll left" onClick={() => { setPosition(position - 250); }}>
            <div className="arrow-left"></div>
          </div>
          : null
        }
        { props && props.relatedProducts && position <= (props.relatedProducts.length - 4) * 250 ?
          <div className="arrow-container-right" role="button" aria-label="scroll right" onClick={() => { setPosition(position + 250); }}>
            <div className="arrow-right"></div>
          </div>
          : null
        }
      </div>
      {modalShowing ?
        <div className='comparison-modal' role='dialog' aria-label='comparison window'>
          <div className='modal-top'>COMPARING</div>
          <div className='modal-product-names'>
            <div className='product-1'>{currentProduct.name}</div>
            <div className='product-2'>{comparisonProduct.name}</div>
          </div>
          <table className='modal-table'>
            <tbody>
              {getFeatures().map((feature, index) => {
                return (
                  <tr key={`${feature}-${index}`}>
                    <td className='left-check'>{currentProduct.features.filter(item => item.feature === feature.feature && item.value === feature.value).length > 0 ? '✓' : null}</td>
                    <td>{feature.value} {feature.feature}</td>
                    <td className='right-check'>{comparisonProduct.features.filter(item => item.feature === feature.feature && item.value === feature.value).length > 0 ? '✓' : null}</td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div className="close-btn" onClick={() => { setModalShowing(false); }}></div>
        </div>
        : null}
    </>
  );
};

export default RelatedProducts;
```

Child component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ratingsAPI from '../../API/Ratings.js';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProductCard = (props) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [averageRating, setAverageRating] = useState();
  const stars = props.generateStars(averageRating, 'related');

  useEffect(() => {
    ratingsAPI.getReviewMetadata(props.product.id)
      .then((metadata) => {
        setAverageRating(getAverageRating(metadata.ratings));
        props.setIsFetching(false);
      });
  }, []);

  const routeChange = () => {
    const path = `/${props.product.id.toString()}`;
    navigate(path);
  };

  const displayComparison = (e) => {
    props.setComparisonProduct(props.product);
    props.setModalShowing(true);
    e.stopPropagation();
  };

  const getAverageRating = (ratings) => {
    var sum = 0;
    var count = 0;
    Object.keys(ratings).forEach(function(rating) {
      sum += rating * parseInt(ratings[rating]);
      count += parseInt(ratings[rating]);
    });
    return sum / count;
  };

  return (
    !props.isFetching ?
      <>
        <div className='product-card-container' onClick={() => routeChange(props.product.id)}>
          <img className='product-card-image' src={props.product.styles.results[0].photos[0].thumbnail_url}>
          </img>
          {props.parentComponent === 'RelatedProducts'
            ?
            <svg className="open-comparison-btn" role='button' aria-label='open comparison' width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" onClick={(e) => { displayComparison(e); }}>
              <path fill="White" stroke="black" strokeWidth="2px" d="M20.388,10.918L32,12.118l-8.735,7.749L25.914,31.4l-9.893-6.088L6.127,31.4l2.695-11.533L0,12.118
            l11.547-1.2L16.026,0.6L20.388,10.918z"/>
            </svg>
            :
            <div className="close-btn" onClick={() => { props.removeFromOutfit(props.product); }}></div>
          }

          <div className='product-card-description'>
            <div className='product-card-category'>{props.product.category}</div>
            <div className='product-card-name'>{props.product.name}</div>
            <div className='product-card-price'>${props.product.default_price}</div>
            <div className='product-card-stars'>{ stars }</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
      : null
  );
};

export default ProductCard;
```

Test:

```
  it('tests that clicking the open-comparison-btn opens the modal window', async () => {
    render(<RelatedProducts
      addToOutfit={() => { return; }}
      yourOutfit={() => { return; }}
      relatedProducts={relatedProducts}
      generateStars={ generateStars }
      isFetching={() => { return false; }}
      setIsFetching={() => { return; }}
    />, {wrapper: Router});
    fireEvent(
      screen.getByRole('button', {name: 'open comparison'}),
      new MouseEvent('click', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
      }),
    );
    const modal = screen.getByRole('dialog', {name: 'comparison window'});
    expect(modal).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer ended up being simply using await before render...

I think it might be because my child component was doing an API call, but I'm not sure why I did not need to use await when rendering and testing the child component separately.